# How to handle the end of javascript while loop

Tags: javascript

```js
function myFunction() {
    var text = "";
    var i = 5;
    while (i > 0) {
        text += "<br>The number is " + i;
        i--;
    }
    text += "<br>The number is " + i;
    if(i==0){
     i=5;
      text += "<br>The number is reset to " + i;
    }

    while (i > 0) {
        text += "<br>The number is " + i;
        i--;
    }
    text += "<br>The number is " + i;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the number decrements to 0 and then reset to its original value and decrements to zero again. If I set it to 5 explicitly, there will be a break (shows reset to 5) in the execution, and I have to add another while loop.

Is it possible to just use one while loop? Is there a better scenario?

Comment: Yes, [recursion](https://medium.com/@zfrisch/understanding-recursion-in-javascript-992e96449e03)

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean variable, like `oneIterationCompleted`, to see if a full iteration has finished. When `i` becomes `-1` for the first time, set it to `true`, and reset `i` to 5:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var oneIterationCompleted = false;
    var text = '';
    var i = 5;
    while (i > -1) {
        text += "<br>The number is " + i;
        i--;
        if (i === -1 && !oneIterationCompleted) {
            i = 5;
            oneIterationCompleted = true;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Another option would be to display `i % 6` instead of `i` while initializing `i` to 11, no extra tests needed:

```js
function myFunction() {
  let text = '';
  for (let i = 11; i > -1; i--) {
    text += "<br>The number is " + (i % 6);
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Can I use the number as the index of an array and use this scenario to go through the array?

Comment: There aren't any arrays here, so I don't think so?

Comment: Should I ask another question or edit the post? I'm thinking about a scenario that also works for array

Comment: Sounds like a new question to me

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to extract the logic and make an external `for-loop`.

```js
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
function loop() {
  var text = "", i = 5;
  while (i > 0) text += "<br>The number is " + i--;  
  text += "<br>The number is " + i;
  demo.innerHTML += text;  
}

function myFunction() {
  var times = 2;
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    loop();
    if (i !== times - 1) demo.innerHTML += "<br>Start over";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Id do something like this:

```
    function myFunction() {
    var text = "";
    var i = 5;
    var count = 0;
      while ( i > 0 && count < 2 ) {
          text += "<br>The number is " + i;
          i--;
          if( i === 0){
              i = 5;
              if( count < 1 ){
                  text += "<br>The number is reset to " + i;
              }

              count++;
          }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var continue = true ;

function loop(ivalue) {
    var i = ivalue;
    while (i>0) {
        text+= "code"
        i--;

    }
   if(continue) loop(ivalue)
}

<button onclick="loop()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="continue = false">Break</button>
```